# Get value of 'p' tag using preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match

I can get value within tag 'p' using below PHP code

```
$pattern ='/<p>(.*)<\/p>/';
$str = '<div class="sample"><p>Hi welcome</p></div>';
preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
print_R($matches);
```

But I've another HTML code which've more space after tag break tag. Here is my code.

```
<div class="boxes-box-content"><p>Call: (+61 3) 8639 9000<br />
 <a href="mailto:info@rgit.edu.au">info@rgit.edu.au</a><br />
  28-32 Elizabeth Street, Melbourne<br />
  VIC 3000, Australia</p>
</div>
```

In above code, there is more space after break tag. So I can't get the value of tag 'p'. 
Is any other method to get value of 'p' tag.

I want to get results as

Call: (+61 3) 8639 9000
  info@rgit.edu.au
  28-32 Elizabeth Street, Melbourne
  VIC 3000, Australia

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: I want to do this using only preg_match()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to parse HTML is by using PHP [DOM Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Though if you still want to use preg_match in this can use below regex (added ) and check,

```
$pattern = "/<p>(.*)<\/p>/s";
```

*[Woking DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/r3JhQa)*.

Comment: @phponwebsites You shall accept the answer if it helps you